# Adding and Removing a Button in JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to add/remove buttons in `JList`. How can I do so?

Comment: down-voted because the OP didn't clarify the (highly unusual) requirement. As a consequence to the unclear requirement, the answers are wide-spread guesses (and most correct for the assumption they did ;-).

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, consider a button-friendly `JToolBar`, as shown in [*How to Use Tool Bars*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html).

Comment: +1 very good point. Yea the toolbar sounds as much better place for buttons.

Answer (score 2):

@rohit I wonder here, what would you need them in a JList? If you want to lay them out vertically you should use some layout manager, e.g. BoxLayout or (better) GridLayout.

There is really no reason why you should have buttons in a JList, where having them in a panel will have the same result.

Seriously try to reconsider your design and go with a more flexible and easier one which uses a layout manager.

All the best, Boro.

Comment: I was thinking that maybe `JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP` with a `SINGLE_SELECTION` model might have some appeal, but a layout of buttons seems more manageable, as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Oracle Swing tutorial about how to use lists:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html

Answer (score 0):

JList.addElement() and JList.removeElement can be used to add en remove elements to and from JLists.

Comment: inventing api might be tempting - but not overly helpful ;-) There are no such methods in javax.swing.JList.

Answer (score 0):

I Used this code. try it

```
class PanelRenderer implements ListCellRenderer {

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        JButton renderer = (JButton) value;
        renderer.setBackground(isSelected ? Color.red : list.getBackground());
        return renderer;
    }
}

public void ShowItemList(List<JButton> buttonList, JPanel container) {


        DefaultListModel model = new DefaultListModel();

        for (JButton b:buttonList) {

                model.addElement(b);

        }
        final JList list = new JList(model);
        list.setFixedCellHeight(40);
        list.setSelectedIndex(-1);

        list.setCellRenderer(new JPanelToJList.PanelRenderer());
        JScrollPane scroll1 = new JScrollPane(list);
        final JScrollBar scrollBar = scroll1.getVerticalScrollBar();
        scrollBar.addAdjustmentListener(new AdjustmentListener() {
            @Override
            public void adjustmentValueChanged(AdjustmentEvent e) {
                System.out.println("JScrollBar's current value = " + scrollBar.getValue());
            }
        });
        container.removeAll();
        container.add(scroll1);
}
```

If you want to add a      JButton       add it to the list. If want to remove, remove it from the list and run the method again.